# Problem Running Dropbox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

I'm trying to get dropbox to run on 16.04, but I'm getting python errors when trying to run the daemon.  I've installed both via the .deb package, as well as compiling from source, both seem to complete successfully, but I always end up with the same python error when attempting to run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File '<string>', line 6 in <module>
  File '__main__.py', line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
```

My python experience is limited. I've tried installing pip to ensure the 'os' module is present but not having any luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the root cause, but I managed to get this working by:

- renaming the `dropbox` binary under `.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.20.1` to e.g `dropbox-exec`
- changing `.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.20.1/dropboxd` to point to `dropbox-exec` insteadof `dropbox`
- unzipping the contents of `library.zip` in `.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.20.1` to the same directory